# Llamar a api antes de cargar el DOM en Angular

Tags: angular, api, dom

Tengo un select cargado desde una api (que tarda su tiempo obviamente), también tengo 3 divs que muestro segun lo que se haya cargado o seleccionado en el select, lo que sucede que al hacer:

```
<div class="panel"  *ngIf="tipoSeleccionado.CantidadMaxima =='2'">
```

Da error diciendo que no existe tipoSeleccionado ya que el la api no trajo aun el resultado y ya quiere mostrar el DIV, como hago para ejecutar la llamada a la api antes que se pinte el div?
Muchas Gracias

Comment: No puedes llamar a una API antes de cargar el DOM, los scripts se ejecutan al momento de cargar la página, para esperar a que se acabe el proceso de consumir una API puedes poner una pantalla de carga y pintar los datos que obtuviste de la API en pantalla y hacer un callback cuando ya hayas recibido todos los datos que necesitas para cargar la página completa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Da error diciendo que no existe tipoSeleccionado ya que el la api no
> trajo aun el resultado y ya quiere mostrar el DIV

Eso es normal y la solución no es llamar a la API antes de cargar el DOM.

La solución es validar que `tipoSeleccionado` no sea `null` antes de acceder a su propiedad `CantidadMaxima`.

Eso se hace con el [encademiento opcional](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Encadenamiento_opcional). De esa forma solo se leerá el valor de `CantidadMaxima` cuando `tipoSeleccionado` ya esté inicializado.

```
<div class="panel"  *ngIf="tipoSeleccionado?.CantidadMaxima =='2'">
```